# How to set a "timer" in ASP.Net Core 3.1 (please read description)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, timeout

I'm looking for a way to set a timer to a specific view in my asp.net core 3.1 applications. For example, the user logsin my application and then is redirected to a page where they can change their password. I wanted to set a timer so that page could only be open for a period of time (e.g 5 min) and if the user didn't change their password in that period, it would automaticaly redirect the user to the login page.
I'm not sure how I should research for this, I've seen some examples with the usage of cookies in the Startup class, but the examples that I've seen are not that well explained. Can someone help me with this?

NOTE: I'm not using the identiy class from asp.net (not sure if this information is relevant)

Comment: You could for sure do that with Javascript, but why do you want to redirect the user after 5 minutes?

Comment: Do you know some documentation that I could follow? I want to redirect the user after a period amount of time for mostly "security" and avoid a man-in-the-middle situation

Comment: I don't understand how that improves security. Man-in-the-middle is prevented with TLS/HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the recommendation on doing this with javascript and it worked! I just added this piece of code at the beginning of the view that I want to be shown for a period amount of time:

```
 <script>
       function Redirect()
       {
          window.location="@Url.Action("<action>","<controller>")";
       }
       setTimeout('Redirect()', 3000000);
</script>
```

NOTE: 300000 miliseconds = 5 minutes

Thank you for your suggestion @juunas.